# Which loss function should I use for binary classification?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, classification, objective-functions, binary-classification

I plan to create a neural network using Python, Keras, and TensorFlow. All the tutorials I have seen so far are concerned with image recognition. However, the goal of my program would be to take in 10+ inputs and calculate a binary output (true/false) instead.

Which loss function should I use for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several loss functions that you can use for binary classification. For example, you could use the [**binary cross-entropy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) or the [**hinge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) loss functions.

See, for example, the tutorials [Binary Classification Tutorial with the Keras Deep Learning Library](https://machinelearningmastery.com/binary-classification-tutorial-with-the-keras-deep-learning-library/) (2016) and [How to Choose Loss Functions When Training Deep Learning Neural Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) (2019) by Jason Brownlee. Have also a look at Keras [documentation of its available loss functions](https://keras.io/losses/).